# how to make perl "escape" strings?

Tags: perl

I am using perl system calls nested from a perl script:

```
$file1 = shift @ARGV;
system("cat file.txt | perl -pi -e 's/OUTPUT/$file1/'");
```

The problem is that if $file1 contains characters such as @, it makes it problematic to use it this way. Is there a way to tell perl that it should "escape" whatever $file1 is containing, instead of treating @... as an array?

Answer (score 4):

[quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html).

But why are you spawning a second Perl process?  You can do it in the the same script.

```
my $file = shift;
{
    local $^I = '';
    local @ARGV = ('file.txt');
    while (<>) {
        s/OUTPUT/$file1/;
        print;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There shouldn't be a need to call perl from inside of perl. Something like this should work:

```
my $file1 = shift;
my @data;
open(my $fh, '<+', 'file.txt') or die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
   $_ =~ s/OUTPUT/$file1/;
   push(@data, $_);
}

seek($fh, 0, 0);
truncate($fh, 0);

for my line (@data) {
   print ${fh} $line;
}
close($fh);
```